# Little glitch in implementing RSA algorithm

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, biginteger

I am trying to implement the [RSA algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#Key_generation), but for some reason my code below doesn't produce correct results (note that only the relevant code is shown).

```
BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);
BigInteger totient = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

Random rand = new Random();
BigInteger e;
do
{
 e = new BigInteger(totient.bitLength(), rand);
} while ((e.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0 || e.compareTo(totient) >= 0)
   && !((e.gcd(totient)).equals(BigInteger.ONE)));

BigInteger d = (BigInteger.ONE.divide(e)).mod(totient);
```

Sample output using 127 and 131 as the prime-number inputs (note that 16637 is correct, but 7683 and 0 aren't):

```
Public Key: (16637,7683)
Private Key: (16637,0)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know for sure but there is a 99% chance that BigInteger d = (BigInteger.ONE.divide(e)).mod(totient); is giving you zero as a result of that divide()

Comment: Jonathan, you may have a point -- the output of the second value of the private key is always 0.

Comment: yup, you can't do a modular divide by an integer divide followed by a mod.

Comment: You're right, Dan, that seems to be the problem. But I don't think I've misinterpreted the RSA algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#Key_generation

Comment: I believe your mistake is assuming that divide().mod() finds modular dividends, which it most likely doesn't. You will need to do something else to find the multiplicative inverse in a modular ring. I believe the extended euclidian algorithm can do this.

Comment: In addition to the modular inverse vs division problem others have pointed out, you should be choosing a small e, rather than a large random one. A common choice is a small Fermat prime (3, 17, 65537) because of better efficiency (as there is only a two 1 bits, which makes exponentiation faster). Choosing a large random e, you might end up with a small d value, and d values smaller than about n^(1/4) are easy to crack.

Comment: @Jack Lloyd: "...choosing a large random e, you might end up with a small d ..." is unlikely to the point of not being worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are correct. You should use the [modInverse()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modInverse%28java.math.BigInteger%29) method of BigInteger to compute an inverse. So the last line should be:

```
BigInteger d = e.modInverse(totient);
```

Also, I'm not completely certain I understand the condition in the while loop. Maybe the last `&&` should be an `||`? Personally, I would use a separate method that returns a random number in the correct range.